# Arcobjects event on featurelayer symbology change

Tags: arcmap, arcobjects, symbology, java, events

I am working on an Java AddIn project for ArcMap. I need to find the event when user changes the symbology for a layer added in TOC.

So far my best bet is to useIActiveViewEvents class on map, and read the symbology after every refresh of the map. That seems to work but does not sound efficient.

Is there anyway to add an event listner which listens on FeautreLayer`s symbology
Or
Is there a way to add event on legend
Or 
is there a way to add an event on the IFeatureRenderer of the layer?