# TOC layer symbol changed EVENTS in ArcMap

Tags: arcobjects, symbology, .net, feature-layer, events

I want to do something when user changes one of TOC layer's symbol. I am using .NET in arcMap 10.0 . How can it possible with ArcObjects ?

Is there any events that will fired when user change symbol of a layer in TOC?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/134114/arcobjects-java-event-on-featurelayer-symbology-change

Comment: I didn't flag this question because your question is about .NET api and not the Java API. Although both APIs resembles each other in many ways.

Comment: Not that I've seen... as with the other question it should fire the 'contents changed' event but no object is passed to indicate which object has changed... perhaps put it to Esri as an improvement request.